# How long elasticsearch stores indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I find out how long elasticsearch stores indexes?

For what period from which date to now.

It's in config elasticsearch.yml? or I need something else?

edit

No, I don't want delete indicies, I want to know, from which date I have indicies.

Comment: as long as nobody deletes it, i think. you can `flush` or `close` the indices the way you want.(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/retiring-data.html) I would simply create cron jobs which would flush the indices if index created date is say 90 days before now.

Comment: Or actually you can use curator - https://github.com/elastic/curator with `action: delete_indices`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing old indices in elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430055/removing-old-indices-in-elasticsearch) / [How to delete elastic search indices periodically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597842/how-to-delete-elastic-search-indices-periodically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Cerebro](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro) (formerly Kopf) or the management view in Kibana (DevTools) for manual operations and peeking around.

An index is deleted or rebuild with REST commands. So only on demand. This is typically scripted to delete by time filters. For example curator [can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430055/removing-old-indices-in-elasticsearch).